# Why does my code give only a single output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm supposed to compare two numbers here taken as input in a single line. My problem is that I'm getting only one output for any number of inputs. I guess I am going wrong somewhere in list iteration. 
Also please tell that why is it wrong if i use " for i in [A] and [B] " instead of "for i in range(len(A)) " ?

```
import math
T = int(raw_input())
A = []
B = []
for i in range(0,T):
 a,b = raw_input().split()
 a = int(a)
 b = int(b)
A.append(a)
B.append(b)
k = len(A)
for i in range(k):                 
    if A[i] > B[i]:
      print ">"
    elif A[i] < B[i]:
      print "<"
    elif A[i] == B[i]:
      print "="
```

Edit : This error was caused by wrong indentation.

Comment: You append to the list outside the loop. This would be more obvious if you weren't using a single space of indentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an intendation problem to me.
Make sure you have `A.append(a)` within the for loop

```
import math
T = int(raw_input())
A = []
B = []

for i in range(0,T):
    a,b = raw_input().split()
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    A.append(a)
    B.append(b)

# k = len(A)
for i in range(len(A)):                 
    if A[i] > B[i]:
      print ">"
    elif A[i] < B[i]:
      print "<"
    elif A[i] == B[i]:
      print "="
```